# Mysql pagination implemented using PHP & HTML Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

Im having an issue with pagination and after trying for several hours to get this working the last resort is stackoverflow! The results of the query display the list of products however the results are displayed all on 1 page and not reflected correctly for pagination. Im not sure where I have gone wrong here.

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
$no_of_records_per_page = 2;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost",".....","....",".....");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
$total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
$total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];

$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
    $product_array = $shoppingCart->getAllProduct($query);
    if (! empty($product_array)) {
        foreach ($product_array as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <div class="product-item">
            <form method="post"
                action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
                <div class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>">
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"
                            size="2" class="input-cart-quantity" />
                        <input type="image"
                            src="image/add-to-cart.png" class="btnAddAction" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price float-left">
                        <?php echo "&pound;".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in that `while` loop? The way you set up queries for pagination is correct. But you don't seem to build html from the results of that query. You build based on products from the shopping cart. Where does it come from? What does it contain? What is the purpose of this page?

Answer (score 0):

**may be it would be helpfull to you**

```
<?php  
    $limit = 3;  //set  Number of entries to show in a page.
    // Look for a GET variable page if not found default is 1.        
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) {    
    $page  = $_GET["page"];    
    }    
    else { $page=1;    
    } 
    //determine the sql LIMIT starting number for the results on the displaying page  
    $page_index = ($page-1) * $limit;      // 0

    $All_Users=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users limit $page_index, $limit");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($All_Users))
    {
        //show  data in table or where you want..
    }
    $all_data=mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) from users");
    $user_count = mysqli_fetch_row($all_data);   // say total count 9  
    $total_records = $user_count[0];   //9
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    // 9/3=  3
    if($page >= 2){
        echo "<a href='blog.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='btn customBtn2'>Previous</a>";
      }
    
    if($page<$total_pages) {
        echo "<a href='blog.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='btn customBtn2'>NEXT</a>";   
    }       
?>
```